# Manipulate Kendo Grid Column Design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to displayed records in grouping,I mean hide the column data if its in same group.Please refer below screen shot.

[image]

Is it possible in Kendo Grid(with asp.net MVC)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The screen shot doesn't show what the words you've written are communicating.  How would it look if I hid the ID & Employee Name column for the rows underneath it that are part of that group?

Comment: Actually i don't want to hide Id and Employee name,due to security reason i have just black out that name and id,i want to display output of kendo grid like above Picture as it is.

Comment: The easiest route I can think of would be to make the font-color transparent in the render event of each row.  Otherwise, the behavior you want is not what the Kendo UI grid (or really, any grid) provides.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using grid hierarchy or aggregates, whichever suits you best.

Here's a [working demo for hierarchy](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy) and a [working demo for aggregates](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates).

Comment: Thanks Thiago,but it is not like that what I actually want to display,Is there any another way or property available to display data in above posted format?